# Way to secure store personal data

Tags: encryption, file-encryption, cloud-storage

This is not for business or corporations, but for personal situations.

I rely on gsuite, google drive, google docs, etc.. not that too much 'heavily', but I use it to send most of my business emails, personal and team docs sharing.

However, there some sensitive infos(like personal info, security keys, really private info that I want nobody to see), and I don't trust google that it will store it secure.

I thought about encrypting it and saving it locally, or encryting it and saving it in cloud.

What is the best way to storage personal and sensitive files?

Encrypting and saving like on a hardware encrypted usb seems like the best, but there is always the risk of losing it.

Is encrypting and saving in the cloud more secure?

Tell me your ways you store your most important and private data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the nature of the data if you are storing. Ultimately it is a security/convenience trade of.

Using strong encryption before you save it to the cloud is very secure as long as your key is strong. The draw back is you lose many features of GSuite as you are effectively now just storing binary blobs.

You also have the problem of sharing yours keys with who ever wants to view the data.

Another option may be to use GSuite for all non sensitive data and roll your own solution like own cloud for sensitive stuff. This does mean you need to set up and secure you own service and server but it gives you total control.